# Make Numbers in a specific column to have the same Length in BASH

Tags: bash, number-formatting, content-length

I need that all the numbers of column 4 to have 4 characters

Input

```
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 12.5 0 0 1
```

desired output

```
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 12.50 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't quite what you're asking for, but provides a consistent width:

```
awk '{$4=sprintf("%06.2f", $4)}1' input
```

which produces:

```
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.00 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.50 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.90 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 012.50 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Willian that was really helpful and easy to apply!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite inflexible but deals with your specific issue:

```
awk 'length($4) == 4 { $4 = $4 "0" }1' file
```

All it does is adds a 0 to the end of the 4th field if it is 4 characters long.

If the requirement is more complex, e.g. the length can vary by more than one digit, then you should update your question to show some different input.

Answer (score 1):

In bash (or POSIX shell), your primary built-in tool for formatting is `printf`. You can read the first 4-columns of each line and the rest in some dummy variable and then print them with `printf` formatting the columns to a specific width each, as required:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 stuff; do 
    printf "%5s %4s %8s %5s %s\n" $c1 $c2 $c3 $c4 "$stuff"
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/agap.txt
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 12.5 0 0 1
```

**Output**

```
$ bash fmtagap.sh dat/agap.txt
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814  12.5 0 0 1
```

`printf` in bash takes the same format string and format specifiers as it does in C. You can read about all the things you can do with formatting in `man 3 printf`. In addition bash adds a few, like `printf -v varname "fmt string"` to format and save the results in `varname`.

One limitation on the format string is padding. While you can `0` pad on the left, you cannot `0` pad a number on the right. Regardless of whether you use a `%s` a string conversion or `%5.1f` a floating point conversion, you are limited to left-padding and field-width specification.

You can, of course, check the length of each variable before printing, and `0` pad on the right that way, but that is about the point where you start asking can a external shell utility do that for me.... But, for completeness:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 stuff; do 
    while [ ${#c4} -lt 5 ]; do
        c4="${c4}0"
    done 
    printf "%s %s %s %s %s\n" $c1 $c2 $c3 $c4 "$stuff"
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash fmtagap.sh dat/agap.txt
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 12.50 0 0 1
```

Comment: Thank you @David! Awesome explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution similar to @William's awk solution:

`perl -lane '$F[3] = sprintf("%06.2f", $F[3]); print join " ",@F' input`

`-a` autosplits each line into the `@F` array

output:

```
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.00 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.50 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.90 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 012.50 0 0 1
```

Using `substr` to produce the format you asked for:

`perl -lane '$F[3] = substr(sprintf("%5.2f", $F[3]),0,5); print join " ",@F' input`

```
AGAP4 2061 0.534207 917.0 0 0 1
AGAP5 2061 0.536148 101.5 0 0 8
AGBL1 3201 0.514214 917.9 0 0 2
AGBL2 2709 0.444814 12.50 0 0 1
```